# Angular Nested Named Outlets Routes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

Hello im trying to nest my outlet routes in angular 9.
whenever i go to `http://localhost:4200/app/(orders:orders)/(order-details:/order-details)` i get redirected to `http://localhost:4200/app/(orders:orders)`
 im trying to have a view where they can see a list of the orders, then when clicked on orders display another view with order details. thanks for help
`routes.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: HomeComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'orders', component: OrdersComponent, outlet: 'orders',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'order-details', component: OrderDetailsComponent, outlet: 'order-details',
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

`home.component.html`

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
    <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>
        Drawer content
        <button (click)="signOut()">signout</button>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <p>hello</p>
        <router-outlet name="orders"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="order-details"></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

`orders.component.ts`

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let order of orders | async">
            {{ order.id }} status is: {{order.status}}
            <button (click)="confirmOrder(order)">confirm order</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <router-outlet name="order-details"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: this is named router outlet. not nested router-outlet.

Comment: and maybe your guard is doing so, check your guard.

Comment: updated the answer below. please check and vote if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Too Much Effort I got the Solution :-

**Solution URL** :- /app/(orders:orders/(order-details:order-details))

**Working Stackblitz :-** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oac197

**Route Config :-**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "", component: LoginComponent },
      {
        path: "app",
        outlet: "primary",
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: "orders",
            outlet: "orders",
            component: OrdersComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: "order-details",
                component: OrderDetailsComponent,
                outlet: "order-details"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { path: "**", redirectTo: " ", pathMatch: "full" }
  ]
    )
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="example-container">
    <div mode="side" opened>
        Drawer content
        <button (click)="signOut()">signout</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<button (click)="navigateToOrders()"> Go To Order </button>
<button (click)="navigateToOrderDetails()">Go To Order Details</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  public navigateToOrders() {
    this.router.navigate(["app", { outlets: { orders: ["orders"] } }]);
  }

  public navigateToOrderDetails() {
    this.router.navigate(["app",{ outlets: {orders: ["orders", {outlets: {"order-details": ["order-details"] }}]}  }]);
  }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<router-outlet name="orders"></router-outlet>
```

**orders.component.html**

```
<p>
orders works!
</p>

<router-outlet name="order-details"></router-outlet>
```

**order-details.component.html**

```
<p>
order-details works!
</p>
```

Comment: so when i move that named router outlet to the orders component. only the orders component renders

Comment: can you tell the statement with which you are navigating?

Comment: `http://localhost:4200/app/(orders:orders)/(order-details:/order-details)`

Comment: ive updated my question to include the `order.component.ts` file

Comment: now when you have children routes why do you want router-outlet with names? you can have multiple router-outlets without name?

Comment: Mark this as answer please

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for the solution url? I see there’s double parenthesis but confuse on why

Comment: Because order-details is child route of orders so it will come inside that orders parenthesis. For documentation even i had to read router api page. Its not that much well documented :(

Comment: Also you can have same config withou any parentesis and outlet name in your url. That is much better practice. But you wanted like this. Hence i gave solution above.

Comment: Can you show me? I’m new to angular so I don’t know what’s the best practice. & yes documentation isn’t that good about named outlet routing

Comment: Remove outlet property from route config, remove name from router-outlets. Change all navigate statements like you do for normal route, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your time!!

Comment: Worked for you?

Comment: wow. looks like i overcomplicated things. thanks so much!!! still confused on how theres multiple outlets but if it works, it works!